# Angular 2 Service Two-Way Data Binding

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services

I have a `salary.service` and a `player.component`, if the salary variable gets updated in the service will the view in the player component be updated? Or is that not the case in Angular 2?

When the page first loads I see the 50000 in the player.component view, so I know the two are working together. It's updating the value that's has me stumped.

**salary.service**

```
export class SalaryService {

    public salary = 50000; // starting value which gets subtracted from

    constructor() { }

    public setSalary = (value) => { this.salary = this.salary - value };

}
```

**player.component**

```
export class PlayerComponent {

    constructor(private salaryService:SalaryService) {}

    public salary = this.salaryService.salary;

    public updateSalary = (value) => { this.salaryService.setSalary(value) };

}
```

**EDIT**

For anyone who wants to see how I resolved the issue, here's the Plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/aFRXHD3IAy0iFqHe5ard?p=preview

Comment: That doesn't have much to do with angular. It's simply JavaScript. Updating a field in an object won't automagically update a field with the same name in another object. I would also advise you to learn the syntax for class methods, and to choose better names: your setSalary method for example doesn't set the salaty. It subtracts the given value from the salary.

Comment: I beg to differ, in Angular 1 the view and the model would "automagically" update...right?

Comment: No, not at all.

Comment: Isn't that what two-way data-binding is?

Comment: No, it's not what two-way data binding is. Two-way data binding is when, thanks to ng-model, the view updates itself when the model changes, and the model updates itself when the user enters something in the input field. There can also be a two-way binding between two scopes (a controller scope, and a directive isolate scope, for example). But what you have there is not binding at all. It's simply copying the value of a field of your service to a field of your component.

Comment: The question misses the most important detail - the view.

Comment: Maybe I went too light in my code example. I will include the view code that shows the button to click and where the values are coming from. Ultimately the view is what needs to get updated, I just kinda figured people would of assumed the view is what needs to be updated.

Comment: @JB Nizet - Thanks for explaining two-way data binding, I guess I was thinking of things in a different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the way that you have it defined the `public salary = this.salaryService.salary` is copying out the value and not assigning the a reference to salary. They are distinct instances in memory and therefore one cannot expect the salary in the player component to be the same as the one in the service.

If you had a player with a salary and passed it to the service to operate on then the view would adjust correctly as it would be operating on the correct object.

That would look like:
**salary.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class SalaryService {
    constructor() { }

    public setSalary = (player, value) => {
      player.salary -= value;
    };

}
```

**player.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { SalaryService } from "./salary.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'player',
  template: `
  <div>{{player.salary}}</div>
  <button (click)="updateSalary(player, 50)" type="button">Update Salary</button>
  `
  providers: [SalaryService]
})
export class PlayerComponent {
    player = { id: 0, name: "Bob", salary: 50000};
    constructor(private salaryService:SalaryService) {

    }

    public updateSalary = (player, value) => {
      this.salaryService.setSalary(player, value);
    };
}
```

Finally, here is a plunker you can mess around with: http://plnkr.co/edit/oChP0joWuRXTAYFCsPbr?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, the memory was something I was not thinking about. I'l play with your Plunker and better understand what's going on.

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but what about calling `salary` right in the the service?   `{{ salaryService.salary }}` Then will that be a single source for memory?

Comment: You could call the service in the component, but that would make the salary the same everywhere for every player.

If you use direct injection, as implied with it being a private constructor variable, then SalaryService is instantiated once and that same instance is put into every player component you make. If that's desired behavior, great, if there is a salary per player then it would be unwise to do it that way.

Comment: Okay, the salary starts out at $50,000 and as a user starts building their team, what ever the value of a player is gets deducted from the $50,000...hopefully that makes sense. If you know anything about Fantasy Football it's like Draft Kings and others. I just tried it locally, as well as Plunker, and it works like a champ! Thanks again for your help and patience.

Comment: Np, a salary pool or spending cap makes sense for being shared on a per user basis.

Glad I could help.