# Angular 6 communication between component and a directive

Tags: angular

I'm trying to make a pop-up menu component in which i can change the color of the menu.
Right now the menu has a directive in which changes the color,  but now i don't to change the color in the pop-up menu itself, i want to do it with another component.

How can i achieve this?
I had read [this article](https://medium.com/dailyjs/3-ways-to-communicate-between-angular-components-a1e3f3304ecb), but not sure if the communication through a service is the right way to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of ways you can do with

Service is one option. Please check the below article to make the service as two way binding.

[Angular 2 Service Two-Way Data Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40410112/angular-2-service-two-way-data-binding)

And other option is `RxJs` , you can communicate with some isolated component through Observable

https://ncjamieson.com/understanding-subjects/

http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#subject

I would suggest to go with Rxjs , So you can subscribe to multiple component if you want, please check the below link which  explain the same kind of scenario using RxJs observable and Angular services

https://medium.com/@MertzAlertz/services-with-rxjs-50ff96ee0d2a

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In addition to above you can also communicate between components via NgRx which is really a great pattern inspired by Redux. I initially start hating NgRx but later I understood the real benefit of it.

> "Redux is not great for making simple things quickly. It's great for
>   making really hard things simple"

Please have a look on the following articles

1. https://alligator.io/angular/ngrx-store-redux-devtools/
2. https://alligator.io/angular/ngrx-entity/
3. https://alligator.io/angular/ngrx-store-redux-state-management/
4. https://www.logisticinfotech.com/blog/easiest-demo-to-learn-ngrx-in-angular-6/

Hope it will help you one day!!