# Angular 6 - Passing variable value

Tags: angular, typescript

Is there any option for how to pass only value from one variable saved in Component1 to a variable in Component2 without any template binding?

I have component Header and Footer, and in the header is a variable test which is boolean and I need pass value from variable TEST to variable TEST2 in Footer component.

I was looking for some solutions with @Input but I did not find any solutions without template bindings as [test]="test"

In short, I just need to pass value from one `.ts` file to another `.ts` file.

I was following this example: [Pass data to nth level child component in Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51959621/pass-data-to-nth-level-child-component-in-angular-4/51960050#51960050)

But variable still is not passed to the component

**HeaderService.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class HeaderService {
    getTheme: boolean;
}
```

**HeaderComponent.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { SideBarService } from '../sidebar/sidebar.service';
import { googleMapConfig } from '../content/google-map/config.service';
import { HeaderService } from './header.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})

export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  Name = 'Menučkáreň';
  Navigation = 'Navigácia';
  nightTheme;

  icons = ['favorites','notification_important'];
  tooltip = ['Obľúbené položky','Zoznam zmien'];

  constructor(
    public sideBarService: SideBarService,
    public mapService: googleMapConfig,
    private headerService: HeaderService
  ) { }

public toggle() {
  this.sideBarService.toggle.emit();
}

public changeDark() {
  this.nightTheme = true;
  this.headerService.getTheme = true;
  this.mapService.changeDark.emit();
}

public changeLight() {
  this.nightTheme = false;
  this.headerService.getTheme = false;
  this.mapService.changeLight.emit();
}

  ngOnInit() { }

}
```

**FooterComponent**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HeaderService } from '../header/header.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-footer',
  templateUrl: './footer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./footer.component.scss'],
  providers: [HeaderService]
})
export class FooterComponent {

  Copyright = 'Copyright 2018 | Vytvoril Patrik Spišák';
  Version = '0.0.1';
  nightTheme: boolean;

  constructor(private headerService: HeaderService) {

    this.nightTheme = this.headerService.getTheme;

   }

}
```

So when I invoke my function **changeDark()** from HeaderComponent.html it does not trigger this.headerService.getTheme = true;

```html
 <mat-grid-tile>
              <button (click)="this.changeDark($event)" mat-icon-button>
                <mat-icon aria-label="Nočný režim">brightness_3</mat-icon>
              </button>
          </mat-grid-tile>
```

**UPDATE**

So I was able achieve what I was needed with this code: Problem was with providers declared in FooterComponent. While were providers declared in FootersComponent I was getting Undefined, when I removed them and keep providers only in app.modules.ts variable is set and read properly.

HeaderService.ts

```html
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class HeaderService {
    nightTheme:boolean;

    get data():boolean{
        return this.nightTheme;
    }

    set data(value:boolean){
        this.nightTheme = value;
    }

constructor(){}
}
```

**Header Component**

```html
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { SideBarService } from '../sidebar/sidebar.service';
import { googleMapConfig } from '../content/google-map/config.service';
import { HeaderService } from './header.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})

export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  Name = 'Menučkáreň';
  Navigation = 'Navigácia';

  icons = ['favorites','notification_important'];
  tooltip = ['Obľúbené položky','Zoznam zmien'];

  constructor(
    public sideBarService: SideBarService,
    public mapService: googleMapConfig,
    private headerService: HeaderService
  ) {}

public toggle() {
  this.sideBarService.toggle.emit();
}

public changeDark() {
  this.headerService.nightTheme = true;
  console.log(this.headerService.nightTheme);
  this.mapService.changeDark.emit();
}

public changeLight() {
  this.headerService.nightTheme = false;
  console.log(this.headerService.nightTheme);
  this.mapService.changeLight.emit();
}

  ngOnInit() { }

}
```

**Footer Component**

```html
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HeaderService } from '../header/header.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-footer',
  templateUrl: './footer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./footer.component.scss'],
})
export class FooterComponent {

  Copyright = 'Copyright 2018 | Vytvoril Patrik Spišák';
  Version = '0.0.1';

  constructor(private headerService: HeaderService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('FOOTER:'+this.headerService.nightTheme);
  }
  
}
```

Comment: You can't... Either use a common service or the template syntax. Components shouldn't be tightly coupled

Comment: You can't access the property of the component , instead you can access the value inside the service in the component where you want't access.

Comment: In your source code you didn't invoke the changeDark and changeLight anywhere , that's the place where you are setting the value to the service. Also I would suggest you to move the source code to the question by editing it and remove the answer.

Comment: Sorry for that, I have already eddited my post. You can see that actually Im calling that function which trigger events which I defined except the last one which I need to pass to Footer component

Comment: @PatrikSpišák, use a getter in your component: Don't declare nightTheme, just: get nightTheme(){ return this.headerService.getTheme;}

Comment: @Eliseo but I dont want invoke whole function from footer component. I have button which is triggered from header component. So when I triggered changeDark, i need also write value which is pushed to variable nighTheme at the same time... What I'm trying to achieve is make theme switcher for Material IO. But I cant switch theme in Footer, while this is seperated component.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you. I clarified my coment in a answer

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at official [angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service) - Parent and children communicate via a service. The idea is to create a service which has some RxJS `Subject` properties. Your components will inject this service and using those `Subject`s - they can interact with each other. Why `Subject`? because you can subscribe and emit values at the same time. For more information - check this article about [understanding subjects](https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-understanding-subjects-5c585188c3e1).

If you're not familiar with RxJS Subjects, as a workaround (but it's not a good solution) - you can just share the values of the same service by changing it properties. But in this case your components cannot be notified if there were any changes. This is why Subjects are good candidate for component interaction via Service.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a service which stores the variable and from which components can access it. More about services here: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4

Answer (score 0):

You can use Angular services for sharing your common data across your components. Please see my answer

[Pass data to nth level child component in Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51959621/pass-data-to-nth-level-child-component-in-angular-4/51960050#51960050)

And other option is RxJs , you can communicate with some isolated component through Observable

[Angular 6 communication between component and a directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51932747/angular-6-communication-between-component-and-a-directive/51933276#51933276)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

@PatrikSpišák, when you use a getter, any change in your application force Angular to "recalculate" the value. The "tip" is that you have anly a variable (the variable is the variable defined in the service). Make a getter make that you can use the "getter" in the .html of the component. You can use the getter to make any change of other variable of the component

**Update 2** (corrected the name of the variables)

Your footer component. footer need know the value of getTheme

```
constructor(private headerService: HeaderService) 
get getTheme()
{
    return this.headerService.getTheme;
}
```

Your header component, header need know the value of nightTheme and can change

```
constructor(private headerService: HeaderService) 
get getTheme()
{
    return this.headerService.getTheme;
}
set getTheme(value)
{
    this.headerService.getTheme=value;
}
//You can do anywhere
this.getTheme=true
```

Your service headerService

```
getTheme:any;
constructor(){}
```

You only has one variable getTheme in headerService (equal you can use another variable). Seeing your code I think you want to referred to "nightTheme"

Comment: But I dont need show value at all. I need just pass value from one variable in.Header.ts to another variable in Footert.ts  Problem is that i have same variable (nightTheme) in Header and Footer component. 

In the header component is button which should change theme from Light to Dark with changeDark() function. So my button does what I expecting but only in the Header component, so I mean, when I hit button, my theme is switch to dark because function set nightTheme to TRUE, but I need set nightTheme to TRUE in FooterComponent at the same time when I hit button in HeaderComponent

Comment: Update the answer

Comment: I have tried your code but does not work... nighTheme variable in Footer component still remain set as False while in Header Component was set to True

Comment: I wrote so quickly and change the names of the function:see the stackbliz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rrv6hs?file=src%2Fapp%2Ffooter.component.ts