# Pass data to nth level child component in Angular 4

Tags: angular

Below is my structure of components in Angular application,

- app.component.html
- units.component.html
- section.component.html

  {{appData.title}}

I'm creating "appData" in the app.component.ts and I want to use that in the third level of child component i.e. in the app-section component.

How I can achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried anything related [Component Interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction) such as `@Input`, `@ViewChild`, or shares services?

Comment: What have you tried to achieve this?

Comment: I have tried @Input but with this I can pass data 1 level down.

Comment: You could chain `@Input()` across each child, till you reach nth level. But this is not way of good programming. Because you have to pipe your data unnecessarily in each child `component`. Instead you may consider using `shared service` to do this.

Comment: I would recommend you to go with Angular services , from the parent component itself you can set the value and can access the value from your child components. Basically you can access the services in any component.

Comment: import AppCompnent into your child component and make a local refrence and then you can access {{appData.titile}} into your nth child component. Make you sure keep AppComponent into providers as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Angular services for sharing your common data across your components. Below are the steps to do that.

**Step 1  - Create an angular service**

```
import { Injectable, } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable()
export class CommonService {
       sharedData:any; //property for get & set
}
```

**Step 2 - From the parent component you can set the value in to the service**

```
import { Component, Input} from "@angular/core";
import { CommonService} from "path";

@Component({
    selector: "parent",
    templateUrl: "./ParentComponent.html",
    styleUrls: ["./style.css"],
    providers: [CommonService]
})
export class ParentComponent {

    constructor(
     private commonService: CommonService} 
    ) {

    }
    ngOnInit() {  
          this.commonService.sharedData= "Your Data"
    }

}
```

**Step 3 - Access the value from your child component**

```
import { Component, Input} from "@angular/core";
import { CommonService} from "path";

@Component({
    selector: "child",
    templateUrl: "./ChildComponent.html",
    styleUrls: ["./style.css"],
    providers: [CommonService]
})
export class ChildComponent {
    someProperty:any;
    constructor(
     private CommonService: CommonService} 
    ) {

    }
    ngOnInit() {  
        this.someProperty=  this.commonService.sharedData;
    }

}
```

> Please make sure that the service are injected in to your App Module
>   , So you can use the same in all your sub modules also.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [

  ],
  imports: [

  ],
  providers: [CommonService],
  bootstrap: [],

})
export class AppModule { }
```

If you want to make the service as two way binding , please go through this link

[Angular 2 Service Two-Way Data Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40410112/angular-2-service-two-way-data-binding)

Comment: What if I am retrieving data asynchronously? Will this work?

Comment: @VaibhavGhorpade in the child directive you can check whether the particluar property null or not using ngIf.. it will only render when you have data

Answer (score 2):

For this scenario you can use a shared service to communicate between components.

create a shared service like this.

```
@Injectable()
export class SharedDataService {

  public set appData(data: any) {
     this._appData = data;
  } 

  public get appData(): any {
     return this._appData;
  }
}
```

And then inject the `SharedDataService` to the `app.component`. And set the `appData` to the service.

**app.component.ts**

```
constructor(private sharedDataService: SharedDataService) {

}

public setAppData(): void {
  this.sharedDataService.appData = this.appData;
}
```

And inject the `SharedDataService` to the `app-section.component` then you can get the `appData` from the service.

**app-section.component.ts**

```
constructor(private sharedDataService: SharedDataService) {

}

public getAppData(): void {
   this.appData = this.sharedDataService.appData;
}
```

Then you can access the `appData` in the template like this.

**app-section.component.html**

```
{{appData}}
```

There are various ways to communicate between components in angular. And that is called **Component interaction**. you can read more about this in the angular official documentation. [Component Interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service)