# Angular 6 How to store part of API Response for use in new HttpGet statement?

Tags: angular

I'm working with an API that requires that I pass certain Id fields to it, such as groupId, in order to return the required data.  The groupId is associated with a given logged in user.  I would like to store groupId in an HttpParam array for reference in other methods.  Here's what I've tried thus far:

```
 getVotes(groupId: number): Observable<Vote[]> {
     let groupId = getGroupById();
     return this.authService
       .get('/votes/' + groupId.toString());

 }
```

In the above, I want to obtain the votes for a given group based on the user's groupId.  To get the user's groupId I've tried this:

```
getGroupbyId(){
   this.http.get(`${environment.apiUrl}/groups`);
}
```

Portions of component.ts are as follows:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.myProfile = this.route.snapshot.data.profile;
this.getGroups();
this.getVotes();
this.getVoteInsights();
this.getProfileInsights();
this.getGroupInvites();
}
private getGroups(): void{
  this.groupService.getGroups()
  .subscribe(
    groups => this.groups = groups
  );
}

private getVotes(): void {
  this.voteService.getVotes(this.groupId)
   .subscribe(
     votes => this.votes = votes
    );
 }
```

The output of the API Call getGroups is as follows:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Sid's Test Group",
    "imageUrl": "",
    "about": "Sid's Test Group",
    "membershipApprovalType": 0,
    "groupInviteType": 0,
    "groupType": 0
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Sid's Test Group",
    "imageUrl": "",
    "about": "Testing Create Group",
    "membershipApprovalType": 0,
    "groupInviteType": 0,
    "groupType": 0
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Sid's Test Group",
    "imageUrl": "",
    "about": "Testing Create Group",
    "membershipApprovalType": 0,
    "groupInviteType": 0,
    "groupType": 0
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Sid's Test Group",
    "imageUrl": "",
    "about": "Testing Create Group",
    "membershipApprovalType": 0,
    "groupInviteType": 0,
    "groupType": 0
},
{
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Sid's Test Group",
    "imageUrl": "",
    "about": "A Test Group created by Sid",
    "membershipApprovalType": 0,
    "groupInviteType": 0,
    "groupType": 0
},
{
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Another Test Group",
    "imageUrl": "",
    "about": "Testing 123",
    "membershipApprovalType": 0,
    "groupInviteType": 0,
    "groupType": 0
}
```

I would like some guidance on how best to store all the groupIds from my getGroupbyId call, passing the selected groupId from the UI and use it in the getVotes call.

Comment: You've shown your service, where is your component?

Comment: Your signatures are a little confusing. I'd expect `getGroupById` to return a `group` when I pass its` id` as a parameter. Instead it seems to return a bunch of groups. It should be named 'getGroups' or something like that

Comment: Create an angular shared service for sharing the group id's across your component . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51959621/pass-data-to-nth-level-child-component-in-angular-4/51960050#51960050

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where rxjs operators really shine.

In your service, you create a `groupId$` property:

```
groupId$: Observable<number>;
```

Then in your constructor set the value to the `http.get()`:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  this.groupId$ = this.http.get(`${environment.apiUrl}/groups`);
}
```

Then anytime you need to use it:

```
getVotes(): Observable<Vote[]> {
  return this.groupId$.pipe(
    exhaustMap(groupId => this.authService
      .get('/votes/' + groupId.toString());
    )
  );
}
```

ExhaustMap maps the `groupId$` observable to the `authService.get()` observable. It will always use the last emitted value of `groupId$` so it's cached in a way.

Comment: Thanks for this response.  The getVotes syntax above is throwing The 'this' context of type 'void' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'Observable[]'.  How would I pass in the selected groupId from a list item?

Comment: I solved the previously reported syntax error by importing from rxjs/operators.  My IDE suggested something else like rxjs/compat which seemed to be causing the error.

Comment: The import statements are different for rxjs v5.5 and newer, vs before 5.5. Check your package.json to make sure you are importing them the right way.

Answer (score 1):

When your `groupId` belongs to a user that is logged in, you should have something like a `PrincipalService` which contains information about the logged-in user, his permissions and very likely his groupId, too. Such a service is typically shared across the whole application. You can inject it into your components and receive the user object/its groupId wherever you like.

Comment: This is a great idea.  I have an authService already in place which controls authorization but a PrincipalService is an excellent addition to this.  Thanks!